# How to remove ambiguous date from the input tool?

Tags: azure-mapping-data-flow

I need to develop this
[alteryx condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SkD6.png) at mapping dataflow level in adf.
I tried by using filter tool to implement this [implemented filter tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGorC.png) .

but when i am performing union tool with this filter tool and with another tool.

getting the error like this
[at union level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLbIE.png).

here the column format is yyyy-mm-dd

I need the correct solution for this issue and how can i implement this alteryx condition in adf at mapping dataflow level can you suggest.

1.there is no column with the same name in filteringonDateBetweenDRO2! 2.the output of the filteringonDateBetweenDRO2 [DatebetweenDRO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6P9C.png).
3. the union settings is [unionsettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKtYG.png).

Comment: 1. Do you have columns with same name in `filteringonDateBetweenDRO2`? 2. Could you share the output data of `filteringonDateBetweenDRO2`? 3.Also share the screenshot of union settings.

Answer (score 0):

> Ambiguous column date

Generally, this error occurs while joining the tables from more than one stream which have same column names. To resolve the error message, you are seeing in the Union transformation, you need to ensure that the schema of the input data flows is compatible and don’t have any obscure column. From the union settings, it is understood that , you are doing union by name. Thus, you need to ensure that the column names and data types of match across all input data flows. If the column names or data types do not match, you can use a Select transformation to rename columns or cast data types as needed.